# Suse 15 nslookup NXDOMAIN

Tags: dns, hostname, suse, nslookup, networkmanager

i have Suse 15 , 4.12.14-25.25-default , using wicked 0.6.52.

when i try to nslookup hostname \ ip i get the error i get :

```
server can't find HOTNAME \ IP NXDOMAIN
```

now the way i got to fix it (temporary for 1 hour or so)
i run this :

```
dhclient -r && sudo dhclient
systemctl restart  wicked.service
service sssd restart
```

and it dows fix it! but then it goes back to not working.
/etc/resolve contains private DNS servers and domaines which work on other servers fine.

what could this be ?
also i have these errors  in /var/log/messages

```
GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Clock skew too great

GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that there the fix is :

Basically just adding this file /etc/wicked/local.xml:

```
  <config>
    <addrconf>
      <dhcp4>
        <create-cid>rfc2132</create-cid>
      </dhcp4>
    </addrconf>
  </config>
```

Save - > restart wicked service \ reboot and check again.

im contacting suse to fix this in the package it self.